# How to print a table fsharp - in columns and rows?

Tags: f#

How do I print a table fsharp - in columns and rows?

```
for j = 0 to 10 do

  printfn "%d " j
  printfn "%d" (sum j)
  printfn "%d" (simpleSum j)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and programming in general :) There isn't enough information in this question to provide an answer. Please can you also provide an example of the output that you expect?

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing the output you want, we can't tell you *exactly* what you'll want to write, but we can tell you the basic building blocks you can put together to get what you want.

First, there are two functions, `printf` and `printfn`. The `printfn` version will print a newline at the end of the text it prints, while `printf` will not. So what you probably wanted was:

```
printf "%d " j
printf "%d" (sum j)
printfn "%d" (simpleSum j)
```

Second, you can actually put multiple `%` codes into the format string of a single `printf` or `printfn` call, and pass all the values you want to print as parameters after the format string. (Make sure the number of `%` codes matches the number of values you supply). E.g.,:

```
printfn "%d %d %d" j (sum j) (simpleSum j)
```

Finally, the `%` codes in `printf` and `printfn` can also include a number before the letter, to indicate the *minimum* number of characters that part of the text should take up. If the text would be shorter than that many characters, it will be padded with spaces to fill out the length. If it would be longer, it will not be truncated. E.g.:

```
printfn "%5d" (2 + 2)   // Will print "    4"
printfn "%2d" (20 * 20) // Will print "400", because it will not truncate
```

Also, you can put a `0` in front of the format number to pad with zeroes instead of spaces instead:

```
printfn "%03d" (2 + 2)   // Will print "004"
```

Or you could put a `-` in front of the format number to have the padding spaces be on the opposite side from usual:

```
printfn "%5d" (2 + 2)   // Will print "    4"
printfn "%-5d" (2 + 2)  // Will print "4    "
```

Putting all these pieces together, you should be able to experiment and figure out how to print the table output you want.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so very much! I will try this out! I am so grateful!!

Answer (score 0):

Since the question is simple, I'll give a simple answer.

In your loop you're printing `j` `sum j` and `simplesum j`.
To make three simple columns with e.g. 4 units of space, you can write,

```
for j = 0 to 10 do
printfn "|%4d|%4d|%4d|" j (sum j) (simpleSum j)
```

The 4 in `%4d` specifies how much space is given.
Assume, that `j` is printing a 5 digit number. Then only four of those will show, as only 4 spaces are given for your `j` variable.

The answer by rmunn has more info on how defined spaces work, as in `%xd` where x is a given integer.